# Repair UEFI boot partition

Tags: linux, debian, boot, uefi

I've installed Debian11 into new hard drive, first I created partitions use with GParted Live tool. There was accident when I created first partition 'efi'. I treid to rename Label it to '/boot/efi' and GParted crashed and stop responing. When booting to GParted again it show all partitionswas created. Debian was installed successfully, but on boot there is error:

```
"Internal hard disk drive not found. To resolve this issue, try to reset the drive. No bootable devices -- strike F1 to retry boot, F2 to enter setup menu, F5 to enter PSA."
```

Dell Pre-Boot System Assessment diagnostics test (ePSA) show no errors, all hardware is OK.
So possibly, the 1st partition,  UEFI was incorrectly created. How to recreate this UEFI partition with necessary content? (from GParted Live CD or other method)

Comment: It not label of ESP - efi system partition but the flags that gparted assigns. And those flags really just create a very long GUID that UEFI then knows is the ESP. Other tools like gdisk use different codes, but assign the same GUID. Make sure ESP is FAT32 with boot/esp flags. I still like to label all partitions, but often just for reference, although I now mount some using labels. You may need to reinstall grub. Use (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: It was designated precisely "Label" of partition, not the Mount point.
Also, the version of GParted I used have no option to specify Mount Point for partition. I specified it in Calamares installer.